# compare string and match List

Tags: c#

Apologies again if my question is properly asked

I  am try to compare two groups with multiple lists, the first Group  `ResourceGroupNotAssignToPrject` is up 7 list and with that I am try to compare all the `ResourceSeq` string against  the second group `employeeResources` list(which is 4) of all the `ResourceParentSeq` string.
whichever from the fist group the match any from the second group add it to `matchedScenario2.Add(NotAssign.A);`
else add it to
`matchedScenario3.Add(NotAssign.A);`

```
foreach (var NotAssign in ResourceGroupNotAssignToPrject.Zip(
    employeeResources, 
    (a, b) => new { A= a, B=b }))
{
    NotAssign.A.ResourceSeq.CompareTo(NotAssign.B.ResourceParentSeq);

    if (NotAssign.A.ResourceSeq.Equals(NotAssign.B.ResourceParentSeq))
    {
        matchedScenario2.Add(NotAssign.A);
    }
    else
    {
        matchedScenario3.Add(NotAssign.A);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem? Does it compile? How it behaves?

Comment: Not sure `Zip` does what you think it does, it matches purely in order of values returned from `IEnumerable`. Can you explain a bit clearer how you want to match values?

Comment: so for example if in the 1st group I have 5 list with Resourceseq of { 14, 10, 6, 11, 23} in that order and in the 2nd group i have 3 list with ResourceParentseq of {14, 23, 16} in that order.
what the code above does is, it on checks the  Resourceseq in group one against the first ResourceParentseq in group two, then checks the second Resourceseq in group one against the second ResourceParentseq in group two, then checks the third Resourceseq in group one against the third ResourceParentseq in group two and stops  there.

Comment: what i want it to do is check the first Resourceseq in group one against the all ResourceParentseq in group two and do the same with the rest of the Resourceseq in group one

Comment: Sorry when you say "5 list with Resourceseq of { 14, 10, 6, 11, 23}" you mean a list of 5 items as opposed to a list of 5 lists, correct? And when you say "check" you mean none of the items in the second list match this particular item in the first

Comment: apologies for not explaining that properly, yes it is a list of  5 list for the first and a list of 3 list for the second. the second lisit of list is a check for first, now if the item ``Resourceseq`` from any of the list of the 5 list of list matches with the ``ResourceParentseq`` item in the 3 list of list put it in this 
  ``matchedScenario2.Add(NotAssign.A);``
else
  ``matchedScenario3.Add(NotAssign.A);``